# Insert formulas in another row of the named range

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with multiple ranges one below the other. The range is only one row with multiple formulas. The formulas would need to be replicated below that row. I would need to resize each one of them with a loop. However as there are multiple ones the End function doesn't work.

```
For i = 1 To 2
resizeSh.Range("tablename").EntireRow.Copy 
Destination:=resizeSh.Range("tablename").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Next
```

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Does anyone have a solution how to find the last row of the named range and insert the same formulas few times again?

I also tried with this, but it instead of 2 it adds 3 additional lines and I cannot find the cause of this:

```
 For i = 1 To 2
  ActiveSheet.Range("range").Cells(1, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert 
  Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
  ActiveSheet.Range("range").Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy
  ActiveSheet.Range("range").Cells(1, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Next
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @SJR screenshot of what I want is added. resizeSh is the current sheet, I also tested with ActiveSheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do, but this might help.

```
With Range("range")
   .Copy
   .Offset(1).Resize(3).Insert shift:=xlDown
End With
```

Comment: Thanks it works.. but it's overwriting values and ranges below it. It should instead shift down everything else as well. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Oops, amended now.

Comment: It still adds more lines for some reason

Comment: How do you mean? It should copy the range 3 times.

Comment: Sorry it's late and I made a mistake in the rest of my code. It's fine now. Thank you very much.. It's an elegant solution.

Comment: It's my pleasure.